# How to call an external object through a method

Tags: java, object, methods, javafx, external

I'm new to Java so probably this a very basic question, so sorry in advance. This is the code I'm trying to make work:

```
public class Main extends Application {     
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();        
        border.setTop(flowPane());

        Scene scene = new Scene(border);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }       
        private FlowPane flowPane(){

            FlowPane fPane = new FlowPane();

            Button btn = new Button("FlowPane1");
            btn.setPrefSize(100, 50);
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            border.setTop(flowPane1());
    }
});

            fPane.getChildren().add(btn);            
            fPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return fPane;
        }           
}
```

Basically I want to have a Flowpane show in a Borderpane with one button, and when I click that button I want to make another `Flowpane(flowPane1)` appear instead of the first one. My problem lies at the `flowPane()` method, the `border.setTop(flowPane1());` line. The border object is not an internal object in the method so what must I do to be able to make it work somehow, or have the same effect? Ignore not having a `flowPane1()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"My problem lies at the flowPane() method, the border.setTop(flowPane1()); line. The border object is not an internal object in the method"*

I'm not familiar with JavaFX, but I think in all Java this should be the case. The `BorderPane` object is not within the scope of the `flowpane()` method, so just make it a class member with a global scope

```
public class Main extends Application {  

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();  <-- Now has a global scope    

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // BorderPane border = new BorderPane();  <-- remove this
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Ofcourse it was something this easy, but like i said, new to java.